# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to +0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$

Tags: calculus

Looking on each function by itself we get $\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{x}=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$ so it is an expression $\frac{0}{\infty}=0$ but when looking at $x=\frac{1}{100}$ we get $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{100}}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{100}}}{\frac{1}{100}}=\frac{1}{10}\cdot 100=10$

Comment: Be careful! The expression you get is actually of the form $0\times\infty$, I.e $\sqrt{x}\times\dfrac{1}{x}\to 0\times\infty$.

Comment: @Demosthene $0\cdot \infty$ (always) =0?

Comment: @gbox Notation like this is messy, which is why you're confused. Yes, literally $0$ multiplied by any number, no matter how large, will still be zero. But in this case you don't have zero multiplied by something that goes to infinity, you have something that *goes to zero* multiplied by something that goes to infinity.

Comment: @gbox For example, look at $\lim_{x\to\infty}x$. Clearly, this goes to $+\infty$. But you could as well write it as $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x}$, where $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$. So it is not a simple product, it is a matter of which function grows faster. And in your case, $x\to x$ grows faster than $x\to\sqrt{x}$. Also, consider using L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{x^{\frac12}}{x^1} = x^{\frac12 - 1} = x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

Note that  $x=\sqrt{x}^2 $, as $x$ is positive, and cancel a factor.

For your confusion, note that you have $0 \cdot \infty$ not $\frac{0}{\infty}$.